# Googe Apps Script Auto Reply Once Per Conversation

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Voice Number and my auto reply setup where it sends an auto reply to every message, can I set it up to only send it once per conversation/person? Not repeatedly while I am continuing the conversation?

Thanks!

My script is below:

```
function autoReplier() {
  var labelObj = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('autoreply');
  var gmailThreads;
  var messages;
  var sender;

 for (var gg = 0; gg < labelObj.getUnreadCount(); gg++) {
    gmailThreads = labelObj.getThreads()[gg];
    messages = gmailThreads.getMessages();
    for (var ii = 0; ii < messages.length; ii++) {

      if (messages[ii].isUnread()) {

        msg = messages[ii].getPlainBody();
        sender = messages[ii].getFrom().slice(16, 74); 

        MailApp.sendEmail(sender, "Auto Reply", "(Auto reply:) Hi, Thanks 
for reaching out, I respond to text messages.......... ");
        messages[ii].markRead();
        messages[ii].moveToTrash();

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of [Gmail AutoResponder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/email-autoresponder/aohckefanobajaljiobafejcdjjefejl) addon that does something similar to what you are looking to achieve with the code.

I store the message IDs of responded emails in the Property Store and also label the responded messages in Gmail with a specific label.

The next time the trigger runs, it only looks for emails that do not contain that specific label and also their ID should not exist in the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an array variable up to save all previous entries.
If you want to save information for new expectations of your script, you can make a sheet with information to not reply again to the same person. You could add a tag to the message to.